# Need help generating JSON from Perl

Tags: perl, json

I have a few structures called Nodes, each with a hash with several important features about the Node.  I have a graph structure that contains a bunch of nodes.  Essentially, I want to iterate over all of my Nodes and create some sort of structure that can convert each node into a JSON element.  That is for each node I should have an element in the JSON file with all its features (its name, its code, its population...all its properties).

I can't seem to figure out how to use JSON:XS...

```
my $nodeHash = {}; # the hash I plan to pass to the to_json function
my $metros = {}; #each metro is a Node with a bunch of features
my @array= (); # an array that I populate with nodes

    #some code to populate the array (these are blessed objects)

$nodeHash->{$metros} =  \@array; # metros has a reference to a list of all nodes
my $json = new JSON;   # this syntax is yielding an error for some reason
$json = JSON->allow_blessed([$enable]); #im not sure quite how this works from the documentation
my $json_string = $json->encode_json($nodeHash);
open(JSON, ">output.json") or die "cannot open file for reading: $!";
    print JSON "$json_string";
```

Comment: I am not familiar with JSON:XS, but let me make a couple of comments. (1) have you tried `my $json = new JSON::XS;` instead of `my $json = new JSON;` (2) your code contains the statement `$json = JSON->allow_blessed([$enable]);`, but where do you set `$enable` (if you don't set it, it's `false`)?

Comment: If you need pass objects into json, you can use `to_json($nodeHash, { allow_blessed => 1 })`. But it will likely don't do what you want, since it converts objects to `null`. For arbitrary representation look on `convert_blessed` option and provide `TO_JSON` method in your `Node`.

Comment: It's conventional to use `[]` to indicate an optional parameter.  This has nothing to do with the anonymous array constructor.  The docs are saying that `allow_blessed` takes one optional parameter, which defaults to true.  But since an arrayref is considered a true value, passing a literal `[$enable]` actually does work to allow blessed objects.

Comment: @cjm you're right about `[$enable]`: I didn't read carefully the docs!

Answer (score 3):

Probably most easy is functional interface. The [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) selects one of [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS) or [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aPP) based on what is installed.

```
use JSON;

my $node_hash = {
    a => [ 'text1', 'text2' ],
    b => [ 'what',  'is', 'this' ],
};

print to_json($node_hash);    # {"a":["text1","text2"],"b":["what","is","this"]}
```